# CActiveRecord findAll() - results inconsistent

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I have an action that fetches results using `CDbCriteria` and also the usage of `offset` and `limit`. Everytime the function runs it is given a new offset based on the current offset and the number of results recieved. Every run it is also limited to 5 results.

```
public function actionGetCompanyActiveSites($startIndex = 0){
  $company_id = $_GET['company_id'];
  if(isset($_GET['start_index']))
    $startIndex = $_GET['start_index'];

  $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
  $criteria->with = array('eventDetails' => array('joinType' => 'STRAIGHT_JOIN', 'with'=>array('event'=>array('joinType'=>'STRAIGHT_JOIN'))));
  $criteria->together = true;
  $criteria->addCondition("event.company_id = $company_id AND active = 1 ");
  $criteria->order = "name ASC";
  $totalRows = Venue::model()->count($criteria);

  $criteria->offset = $startIndex;
  $criteria->limit = 5;
  $companySites = Venue::model()->findAll($criteria);
  $startIndex += count($companySites);

  echo $this->renderPartial('_activeSites', array('companySites'=>$companySites, 'startIndex'=>$startIndex, 'totalRows'=>$totalRows), false, true);
  Yii::app()->end();
}
```

The first two runs it gets 5 results per run correctly as it should. But then e.g. on the 3rd run it only gets 2, 4th run 1 and on the 5th run 3 etc. For this current scenario I have 21 results available. it should get 5 results for the first 4 runs and then 1 result for the last 5th run.

What is causing the results fetched to be inconsistent? Did I mess up somewhere badly in my code?

Comment: I once had a similar problem. Mine was caused by the join. Try switching the order of the join i.e left, right.